# How can I make scala.scalajs.js.typedarray classes available to JVM builds of scala.js crossprojects?

Tags: scala.js, sbt-crossproject

When I try to access `Uint8ClampedArray` from code running on the JVM, I get the error: `java.lang.Error: A method defined in a JavaScript raw type of a Scala.js library has been called. This is most likely because you tried to run Scala.js binaries on the JVM. Make sure you are using the JVM version of the libraries.`

What JVM library might resolve this run time error?

Do we have other ways to share this data structure across the JS and JVM builds of sbt-crossprojects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot. `Uint8ClampedArray` is a class defined by the JavaScript standard library. It simply does not exist on the JVM.

You might want to look at [`java.nio.ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) for a portable solution, but keep in mind that it doesn't have the *clamped* behavior of `Uint8ClampedArray`. You'll have to wrap in a custom helper if you want that.

Comment: Thank you for articulating this, sjrd.

Right now I'm pursuing a design that abstracts this array data at a higher level and leaves low level manipulations to separate JVM and JS implementations.